# Docker can not find Android SDK and NDK directory

Tags: android, docker

I've created a docker container in order to run my gradle tasks on it.
I'm downloading the sdk inside it, but when I run a task from outside it says that the sdk folder can not be found because it's getting the path I have in the local.properties file of the project. Which is pointing to my machine sdk folder. How can I specify the sdk folder inside the docker image? Thanks.

Docker image build file:

```
FROM openjdk:8

ENV SDK_URL="https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip" \
    ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/android-sdk" \
    ANDROID_NDK_HOME="/usr/local/android-sdk/ndk-bundle" \
    ANDROID_VERSION=26 \
    ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=26.0.2

# Download Android SDK
RUN mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME" .android \
    && cd "$ANDROID_HOME" \
    && curl -o sdk.zip $SDK_URL \
    && unzip sdk.zip \
    && rm sdk.zip \
    && yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses

# add to PATH
ENV PATH ${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}

ENV ANDROID_NDK_HOME /usr/local/android-ndk
ENV ANDROID_NDK_VERSION r19
ENV NDK_URL="https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-${ANDROID_NDK_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.zip"

# Download Android NDK
RUN mkdir "$ANDROID_NDK_HOME" \
    && cd "$ANDROID_NDK_HOME" \
    && curl -o ndk.zip $NDK_URL \
    && unzip ndk.zip \
    && rm ndk.zip

# add to PATH
ENV PATH ${PATH}:${ANDROID_NDK_HOME}

# Install Android Build Tool and Libraries
RUN $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update
RUN $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION}" \
    "platforms;android-${ANDROID_VERSION}" \
    "platform-tools"

RUN mkdir /application
WORKDIR /application
```

This is how I run the task:

```
docker run -it --rm -v "$PWD":/application packsdkandroiddocker.image sh -c "$@" ./gradlew clean
```

And this is the error I get:

> NDK is missing a "platforms" directory. If you are using NDK, verify
>   the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to
>   /Users/adalpari/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle. If you are not using
>   NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties
>   to remove this warning.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>     The SDK directory '/Users/adalpari/Library/Android/sdk' does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove local.properties file from your root folder as SDK is then searched locally which container cannot access.